# Update method on ConcurrentDictionary implemented with Lazy<T> does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, lazy-initialization, concurrentdictionary

As described in [this](https://andrewlock.net/making-getoradd-on-concurrentdictionary-thread-safe-using-lazy/) blog article, I used the `Lazy<T>` class to make my `ConcurrentDictionary` thread-safe. I created a new class called `LazyConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which stores a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>` internally. To update the values stored in my internal dictionary, I want to implement an update method. As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryupdate?view=netframework-4.8), I need to specify a key with its current corresponding value, as well as a new value with which the current value should be replaced with. This only works of course if the specified current value equals the actual value represented by the key in the internal dictionary.

When I try to implement the update method as following, it turns out that the update does not happen:

```
public bool Update(TKey key, TValue currentValue, TValue newValue)
{
    return dictionary.TryUpdate(key,
    new Lazy<TValue>(() => newValue, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
    new Lazy<TValue>(() => currentValue, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication));            
}
```

I assume it's because of the equality comparison between two `Lazy<T>` objects. Even though the underlying objects are instantiated and equal, the `Lazy<T>` objects aren't. Am I correct with my assumption?

However, I want to implement an update method for my `LazyConcurrentDictionary` and need some kind of workaround or another solution. Is there any you can think of?

Comment: Why do you need a `Lazy<T>` ? Just to avoid the scenario described in the article ? In my opinion this is an overkill, you could simply use other means of updating the dictionary like for example TryGet. Something along the lines of: `if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) && value == currentValue) dictionary[key] = newValue`

Comment: @Fabjan Well, the situation the article describes is the situation where computing the value is both expensive and shouldn't be repeated (possibly because it causes side effects).  You can't just avoid it universally.  Your proposed alternative is not safe.  The dictionary can change in between every single operation performed on the underlying dictionary (that's the whole point of `ConcurrentDictionary`) meaning you could end up overwriting the value when it doesn't equal the comparison value, thus not meeting the requirements of the method.

Comment: Your `Update` method doesn't make much sense to me. Normally you would like to use the `Lazy` class when you would like to defer the instantiation of the wrapped value. In your case the wrapped value is already instantiated, since it is passed as an argument (`TValue newValue`) of the `Update` method. So what's the point? If the whole purpose of using the `Lazy` was to avoid creating multiple values for the same key, the purpose has already been defeated.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `TryUpdate` does not accept an `IEqualityComparer<TValue>` to compare the values, so you're forced to use your own type instead of the framework `Lazy` if you want it to use value equality (also realize that, by necessity, comparing the values will resolve both lazy instances).  Fortunately this is pretty easy to do.

```
public class MyLazy<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> valuecomparer;
    public MyLazy(IEqualityComparer<T> valueComparer = null)
    {
        this.valuecomparer = valuecomparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MyLazy<T> other = obj as MyLazy<T>;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return valuecomparer.Equals(Value, other.Value);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return valuecomparer.GetHashCode(Value);
    }
}
```

So you'd need to use that class throughout your own concurrent dictionary implementation, rather than `Lazy`.

Having said all of that, if performance is a major concern, you'd probably be better off simply not using ConcurrentDictionary combined with Lazy to do this, and writing your own stuff from scratch, but doing it in such a way that you take the time to ensure calls to GetOrAdd only resolve the parameters once, unlike ConcurrentDictionary.  If you're going so far as to make a new class it gives off the impression that you're using it enough to potentially need that.